# Hide and Collapse Columns in a Report

Tags: ms-access, report

I have a db with different counties.  Each county has varied lists of trainings for their employees.  Instead of creating a report for each county, I'm trying to produce a report that includes all the trainings.  When filtered by county, I want to hide the trainings that don't pertain to it.

I should be able to code which columns or textboxes to hide. The main problem is changing a column, or textbox, property to Visible:No leaves a gaping hole in the report.  I'd like to hide, and collapse the column.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a non-normalized data structure. What you want is not practical with report. Edit question to post sample data.

Comment: And show a stab at an [mcve].

Comment: The way I would go about it is by not having fixed control sources. Assign control sources using VBA when the report opens and hide the right-most ones.